# Is there any other way to see questions for the last few days sorted by votes?

Tags: support, search

I need to see see questions on Stack Overflow for the `javascript` tag for the last few days sorted by votes. Is there any possibility to do that without using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer? It gets updated only once a week and doesn't have the data I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the SE search*

```
created:06-14-2016.. user:me is:q
```

and [sort the results by votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a06-14-2016..%20user%3Ame%20is%3Aq). You may also change the date to get the less recent questions.

E.g., [here are your questions sorted by votes and filtered to **[javascript]** since June 1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2545680+created%3A06-1-2016..+is%3Aq+%5Bjavascript%5D).

Or, since you probably want to get all the questions, not just yours, just remove the `user:...` part.

---

* `..` implies *to* (or *until*), and as I haven't specified what to, it's considered to be *today*.

Comment: thanks, how can I see all `javascript` questions for the last two days?

Comment: @Max You mean, not only yours? Then just remove `user:...` from the search terms.

Comment: @Maximus just add `[javascript]` to the search box

Comment: @Sha But I've already done that?

Comment: [No you didn't](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jm7LJ.png).

Comment: @Sha But you have clicked the link, haven't you?

Comment: @Sha Look at "E.g." and please read the title of the link.

Comment: @Sha Or is it unclear and I should rephrase it?

Comment: @nicael, thanks, you wrote `created:06-1-2016` - is it the date _from_ until _today_?

Comment: @Max `..` means "to", and if nothing is specified after, it's *today*.